# Overriding iostream << results in error - C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11, overriding

I am creating a class of Rational fractions like many others have before for a C++ Learning exercise.

One of my requirements is to override the `<<` operator so that I can support printing the "fraction", i.e. `numerator + '\' + denominator`

I have tried following [this example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4107/Using-C-operator-overloading-to-make-a-simple-frac), and that seems to be in line with [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653944/overloading-for-a-fraction-class-c) and [this example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162338/a-minimal-fraction-class-in-c), yet I still get compilation errors:

```
WiP2.cpp:21:14: error: 'std::ostream& Rational::operator<<(std::ostream&, Rational&)' must have exactly one argument
   21 |     ostream& operator << (ostream& os, Rational& fraction) {
      |              ^~~~~~~~
WiP2.cpp: In function 'int main()':
WiP2.cpp:39:24: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'Rational')
   39 |     cout << "Two is: " << two << endl;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~
      |          |                |
      |          |                Rational
      |          std::basic_ostream<char>
```

My code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rational
{
    /// Create public functions
    public:

    // Constructor when passed two numbers
    explicit Rational(int numerator, int denominator){
        this->numerator = numerator;
        this->denominator = denominator;    
    }

    // Constructor when passed one number
    explicit Rational(int numerator){
        this->numerator = numerator;
        denominator = 1;    
    }

    ostream& operator << (ostream& os, Rational& fraction) {
    os << fraction.GetNumerator();
    os << '/';
    os << fraction.GetDenominator();

    return os;
    }

    private:
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
}; //end class Rational


int main(){
    Rational two (2);
    Rational half (1, 2);
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    cout << "Two is: " << two << endl;
}
```

Why am I unable to use the override function in the `Rational` class to override the `<<` operator?

Edit - I see some are suggesting the use of a `friend`. I don't know what that is, and am doing some preliminary investigation. A possible working comparison of using a friend for my situation could be beneficial to me as OP and others who are faced with similar implementation-type problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should operator<< be implemented as a friend or as a member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236801/should-operator-be-implemented-as-a-friend-or-as-a-member-function). TL;DR - prefix the signature with `friend`.

Comment: You should either declare it as a member function with one argument, or as a free-standing function with two arguments. But not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These functions can't be implemented from within the class as they need to have global scope.

A common solution is to use a `friend` function https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend.

Using `friend` functions I got your code to compile here https://godbolt.org/z/CWWv0p

Comment: Please add code to the answer so I can accept.